# MT4/MQL4 EA Modification erro

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, mt4

I have an MT4 EA, trying to modify it, I'll share the part I need to modify it below:

```
void exit()
  {
   for(int i=OrdersTotal()-1; i>=0; i--)
     {
      if(OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_TRADES))
        {
         if(OrderSymbol()==Symbol() && OrderMagicNumber()==Magic)
           {
            if(OrderProfit()<0) //LOSS
              {
               amountloss=amountloss+OrderProfit();
               TotalLotLoss=TotalLotLoss+OrderLots();
               lot=lots;
               wincount=0;
              }
            else  //profit
              {
               if(wincount==0)
                 {
                  TotalLotLoss=TotalLotLoss+OrderLots();
                  amountloss=amountloss+OrderProfit();
                  lot=TotalLotLoss*multi;
                  wincount=1;
                 }
               else
                 {
                  TotalLotLoss=TotalLotLoss+OrderLots();
                  amountloss=amountloss+OrderProfit();
                  if(amountloss>0)
                    {
                     TotalLotLoss=0;
                     amountloss=0;
                     lot=lots;
                    }
                  else
                    {
                     lot=OrderLots();
                    }
```

After 1 win it duplicate all losses by 2 and keep doing this until all losses are recovered, what I want is after 1 recovering win, reset to 0.01

I will give you example:
0.01 loss
0.01 loss
0.01 loss
0.01 loss
0.01 win
0.04 win
then reset to 0.01
that's all

I couldn't figure how to do it! any help?

Comment: ...`if(amountloss>0) ` set the `lot` if it it the one used to open next deal, to the starting lot (0.01 in your case).

Comment: it works Daniel! Thanks, but what if I need it to reset if the volume exceeds 1 lot?

Comment: set the amount that you need. I do not understand the question, if it is about programming - show your example, attempts made and problem remaining. if it is about the logic - I dont think SOF is the right place, there are plenty of trading forums.

Comment: Like this: if lots>1 set lots to lots÷2

Comment: and what is the problem to implement that logic? `if(lots>1) lots=lots/2;`

Comment: Daniel, when I try to add the (/) sometimes it keeps dividing until lots go to 0.005 and order can't be opened

Comment: create an MCVE with the bug, not the whole code

Comment: I tried to add it at the end of (else//profit) but I got a lot of errors while compiling, where should I add it exactly?

Comment: maybe you missed to close brackets or plenty of other reasons may lead to that.